# Wordpress plugin setting data

Tags: wordpress, plugins, setting

I want to know that where the plugins settings data saved in server? Means, when we change any plugin settings (e.g. For simple captcha, it is settings as-> use number, user alpha, captcha color etc), then in which file or database , these settings are saved.

Answer (score 26, accepted):

All settings of the Plugin will be saved in the db.

Your Plugin can choose which table they wanted to store the setting into. Check the source code of your Plugin.

- If your Plugins uses `get_options()`, then it will stored in the `wp_options` table
- If your Plugins uses `get_post_meta()`, then it will be stored in the `wp_postmeta` table
- If your Plugins uses `get_comment_meta()`, then it will be stored in the `wp_commentmeta` table

Your Plugin might also have created its own table to store the settings.

Answer (score 1):

Inside WordPress database you will look a table like 'wp_options'. During wp install ,If you use your table prefix 'xyz'. Inside database your table name will 'xyz_options'. If you use WP Setting API and options.php, your plugin data will save in this table.

```
<?php
$data= $GLOBALS['wpdb']->get_results( 'SELECT * FROM xyz_options', OBJECT );
echo '<pre>';
print_r($data);
echo '</pre>';
?>



https://codex.wordpress.org/Options_API
https://codex.wordpress.org/Database_Description#Table:_wp_options
https://codex.wordpress.org/Class_Reference/wpdb
```